# jquery submit() wont do anything

Tags: jquery

Having problem with jquery submit(). The problem is that it doesn't work on the site, it sends me to the action url (as im using get) instead of preventing it and running the function inside the submit(). It works if add the submit()-script in the console. How come?

This is my js file:

```
$(function(ready){
  $('#contact-form button')
    .removeClass('disabled')
    .removeAttr('disabled');

  $('#contact-form').submit(function(e){
    alert('????????????????????????????');
    return false;
      e.preventDefault();

      $this = $(this);
      $this.addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', true);
      $('#contact-form img').addClass('showLoader');

      $.post('theme/widgets/contact-form/ajax/send-mail.php', $('#contact-form').serialize(), function(d){
        $this.removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#contact-form img').removeClass('showLoader');

        try {
          $msg = $.parseJSON(d);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e, d);
          $msg.error = true;
          $msg.message = "Unknown error occoured. See console for more information.";
        }

        if (!$msg.error) {
          $('#contact-form input').val('');
          $('#contact-form textarea').val('');
        }

        alert($msg.message);
      });
  });
});
```

And this is my form:

```
$html = "<form id='contact-form'>
  <label>".__('name', false, $ld)."</label>
  <input type='text' name='name' /><br />
  <label>".__('email', false, $ld)."</label>
  <input type='text' name='email' /><br />
  <label>".__('body', false, $ld)."</label>
  <textarea name='body'></textarea><br />
  <img src='".THEME."images/ajax-loader-small.gif' />
  <button class='disabled' disabled='disabled'><span>".__('send', false, $ld)."</span></button>
</form>";
```

How come the jquery submit only reacts if i paste it into the console and not when the page loads? I am not getting any javascript errors and have tried with a lot of different jquery versions.

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/pEwnX/

Comment: What the conflict on my site? Form is on http://www.redward.se/

Comment: Your form doesn't have a submit button. That's probably why it's not working. Although the use of delegates "fixed" it... it seems to be more of a lucky hack than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the event is not firing. The code, you said, executes fine... after you fire the event manually. The events could not be firing for a few reasons... the first is usually because the events are wired up before the html is rendered. You could solve this by using delegates, but I believe (after 'solving' the problem) that your event is not firing because the event you are wiring is on `form submission` but `you do not have a submit button on your form`. You may want to try making the button a submit button, or making the code fire on the button click instead of the form submit.

Here's the code for using [`delegates`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$("body").delegate("#contact-form", "submit", function() {
    alert('????????????????????????????');
    return false;
      e.preventDefault();

      $this = $(this);
      $this.addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', true);
      $('#contact-form img').addClass('showLoader');

      $.post('theme/widgets/contact-form/ajax/send-mail.php', $('#contact-form').serialize(), function(d){
        $this.removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#contact-form img').removeClass('showLoader');

        try {
          $msg = $.parseJSON(d);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e, d);
          $msg.error = true;
          $msg.message = "Unknown error occoured. See console for more information.";
        }

        if (!$msg.error) {
          $('#contact-form input').val('');
          $('#contact-form textarea').val('');
        }

        alert($msg.message);
      });
});
```

jQuery 1.7 call (recommended, delegates are much more efficient in 1.7 than older versions):

```
$("body").on("submit", "#contact-form", function() {
  //code here
});
```

Comment: No. The form comes from a php file.

Comment: It could also be that you don't have a submit button on your form. You could change the event to button click

Comment: `<button class='disabled' disabled='disabled'><span>Skicka</span></button>` give that button an ID and try to run the event on `$("#skicka").click(function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

I think your button may need a type="submit" for it to work.
That's what the jquery docs says anyway

http://api.jquery.com/submit/